# How do I make a custom LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I need to make a LinearLayout with title on top of it. Kinda look like this 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLvcC.jpg
Does anyone knows how to make one like this?

Edited :
Here is my border drawable which I set as my layout background

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<corners
    android:topRightRadius="30dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp" />
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: your image can not be loaded, but I post an anwer in below. I hope that useful for you.

Comment: Sorry for that, but basically I'm making a LinearLayout with TextView on top of it. TextView's position is above the border. Here's a new link https://ibb.co/jCDC26

Comment: I change several things that can be helpful. you must create a drawable xml file and set as background of Linearlayout.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class that extend from Linerlayout. then in onCreate method you mast inflate a xml layout.

```
public class ValueSelector extends Linerlayout {

View rootView;
TextView valueTextView;

public ValueSelector(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public ValueSelector(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    //do setup work here
    rootView = inflate(context, R.layout.your_custom_view, this);
}
}
```

Then in `your_layout_view.xml` write your custom view like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drwable.boarder_bd"
tools:context=".LinearLayout" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="My Data"
            android:paddingTop="10px"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but what I need is the title must be on top of the border, just like the picture I sent.